# Parsing json with javascript and displaying results error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am parsing a json feed with javascript and then displaying the results.  I am also using jquery mobile.  I find that when I parse and then display, a bullet appears for one of the li's and I don't why it's showing.

When I try to just statically display the results, this li bullet doesn't show.  Any ideas on why this is happening?

Parsing json + displaying:

```
         $("#results").append('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="a" style="white-space:normal">   <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide">  <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-c ui-corner-top">'+item.business.name+'</li> <li class="custom_listview_img" style = "background-image:url('+item.images.image_smart+');"></li></a></ul>');
```

Static display:

```
         <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="a" style="white-space:normal"> 
            <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide">
            <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-c ui-corner-top">Himalayan Flavors</li> 
            <li class="custom_listview_img" style = "background-image:url('http://c.yipitcdn.com/thumbor/SOWRPRFYvkagojw-sA_VPeSKK_k=/408x357/smart/c.yipitcdn.com/deal/20-to-spend-on-food-and-drink-3761-1374483321.jpg');"></li>
        </a>
        </ul>
```

Comment: There's **no JSON** in the code you've shown. You do seem to have an _object_ called `item`, but since you don't show any details of that object we'd just be guessing about whether you're using it correctly... Also, it's invalid html to have an `<a>` tag as a (direct) child of a `<ul>` element.

Comment: The json works as I'm getting results shown.  My question is why the <li> is displaying in the .append.

Comment: You don't need to add classes when appending items dynamically. This will result in duplicate styling. Just add data role, data transition, custom styles and then call `$('ul').listview()` or `listview('refresh')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a styling issue, do:

```
ul {list-style : none;}
```

in CSS to remove the bullets

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zEBGH/1/)

Comment: When I try this, there is still some margin on the left where the bullet would have been.

Comment: @sharataka - It's supposed to be like that, but set the padding to 0, and it's gone

Comment: Jquery mobile way, enhance markup `$('ul').listview();` after appending items dynamically http://fiddle.jshell.net/Bj7bb/

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason of this is their is a onload js that is changing the style of your list. so once the page is loaded. It is not called.

try calling expicilty
eg after your code put

```
$("#listview").css("list-style-type","none");
```

And importantly **THEIR IS NO JSON IN YOUR GIVEN CODE**